# Red boundary around text boxes on Meta.SO?

Tags: discussion, design, meta

This is about this meta site itself, not about Stack Overflow. I can't reproduce it anywhere else.

[image: Search box on search page with red boundary]

This also happens for comments.

Is this a bug, or is it intended behavior? If it's intended behavior, why? Red boundary is normally for errors.

[image: "Ask question" page on main, with invalid title]

Also, it's blue in other places. That's inconsistent.

[image: Search box on top of page with blue boundary]

Comment: @pnuts ... well I think so ... should I ask "is this a bug?" instead? Plus, red has always been indicating something wrong...

Comment: @pnuts Changed, I suppose.

Comment: I didn't notice that because it's not a box. *changing username to ⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕*

Comment: Should be more freehand look for meta.

Comment: There's a CSS class for it, so presumably this is `status-by-design`: `input[type="text"]:not(.s-input):focus, input[type="email"]:not(.s-input):focus, input[type="password"]:not(.s-input):focus, textarea:not(.s-input):focus {
    outline: 0;
    border: 1px solid #C91D2E;
}`

Comment: Yes, this is *by design*. It's the style for the 'active input box'.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Well, good to know. Still, I think it's a very bad design decision. https://i.stack.imgur.com/ueB21.png

Comment: @pnuts: I'm not the designer here. I should perhaps have qualified as: "according to the stylesheet".

Comment: @HereticMonkey Where did you find the ungolfed css? Or you just prettify it? [This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126135/where-can-i-find-the-original-css-files-of-stackoverflow) doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I just right-clicked on the element and selected Inspect in Chrome. There's a `:hov` in the top right of the Styles panel, hit that and check `:focus` and it shows the unminified CSS rules applied to the element.

Comment: @HereticMonkey So it's unminified code, not source code? (disappointing.)